# ASP.NET MVC 5 Database First problem filtering Index results

Tags: sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

My wife owns a dog school. I'm creating an application where she can manage customers, courses, articles, dogs, and invoices.

I created a SQL database which includes these different tables and subtables.
In Visual Studio used ADO.NET Identity and database first.

For example, table customer looks like this:

(Kunde-> Customer, Strasse -> Street, Hund-> Dog)

```
public class Kunde 
{
    public int KundenID { get; set; }
    public int AnredeID { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public int Hausnummer { get; set; }
    public int OrtID { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Aktiv { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AGBDatum { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HundID { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Anrede tbl_Anrede { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Hunde tbl_Hunde { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Ort tbl_Ort { get; set; }
}
```

Now in this table are different FK (foreign keys) like Hund/DogID which points to the table dog where you can manage the dog (age, name, gender, ...) and so on.

My problem is that I don't know how to create or display specific columns. For example, if I add a new customer by default the view shows me the ortID which points to postal code and city (another table). I want to have two fields like a city and postal code. With classic Winforms, I was able to define via SQL statement in which table a value should be inserted or updated.

It's a little bit difficult for me to explain my problem if you need any further information let me know.

Thanks for your response

Comment: The basic pattern of MVC for an edit is to grab the existing data in the controller GET, display the view then POST it back if it is valid. For basic use cases, you could just pass your entity model and load the lookup tables in say a ViewBag. For most apps you will probably want to build a viewmodel with all the fields from all the involved tables and include lists of lookup values. Then when POSTing you will need to update the appropriate entities. Lots of good tutorials out there.

Comment: FYI you will likely want your Hund/DogID to NOT be a foreign key in your CustomerTable, but rather have your CustomerID be a foreign key in your dog table. This way when you can create many dogs for one customer and won't have to create different customers for 2 different dogs with the same owner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback Steve and Colby. Colby of course it makes sense to "turn around" the foreign key so that's customerID is a foreign key. I didn't think about that.

Comment: And Steve: The viemodel is excatly my problem. I don't know how to create the viewmodel. For example: I create a view Model with my customer model data (including OrtID) and the  OrtID model with postal code and city. If the User now enters data i want that postal code and city are filled in one table and the other data is stored to customer table/model. The OrtID parameter should be automaticlly filled. Any idea?